# Uso do verbo "saber" no sentido de "ter sabor ou gosto"

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu

Há um tempo assisti a um programa de entrevistas onde o apresentador (brasileiro) conversava com um português e ambos falavam sobre diferenças nos *portugueses*. Um dos assuntos discutidos foi o uso do verbo *saber* no sentido de ter sabor ou gosto. A frase usada como exemplo foi algo como:

> Hum, esta sopa me *soube* muito bem.

Ao ouvido brasileiro este uso parece estranho, no mínimo incomum. Sei que é um uso válido (segundo o [Dicionário Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/saber)), mas minha pergunta é sobre como este uso soa a um português? Este uso é habitual em pt_pt?

Comment: *Hum, esta sopa soube-me muito bem* ou *Hum, esta sopa é que me soube bem*

Comment: Gmauch e Jorge: há coisas que sabem melhor que sopa, e eu tinha-me esquecido de as incluir. Estive a remediar isso.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normalíssimo da Silva em Portugal e pelos vistos não completamente desconhecido no Brasil. Encontrei o verbo em autores brasileiros recentes. O Aulete digital tem também a definição relevante, e não a restringe a Portugal:

> [***Saber***](http://www.aulete.com.br/saber) **9** Ter sabor; ter sabor de ou parecido com o sabor de [int. : Experimente este vinho, veja como ele sabe!] [tr. + a : Seus beijos sabiam a mel e canela.]

Por curiosidade, *saber* herdou os dois significados, ter conhecimento e ter sabor, do [latim *sapere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sapere). Mas no português difere na primeira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo: *eu sei* (tenho conhecimento); *eu saibo* (tenho sabor).

Todos os exemplos seguintes seriam frases comuns em Portugal, incluindo as dos autores brasileiros. Todo os autores citados são brasileiros (negrito meu).

> Hum, esta sopa **soube-me** muito bem.
>
> Cristina se sentara à mesa. Tomava a sua canjica, mas esta já **não lhe sabia bem**. ([Rachel de Queiroz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_de_Queiroz), *O Galo de Ouro*, 1985.)
>
> Este bacalhau **soube-me** que nem ginjas (= soube-me mesmo muito bem).

Também é possível a conjugação não pronominal. Nesse caso, estás a dizer que o que o sabor que detetaste é uma coisa objetiva com a qual toda a gente concordaria:

> Baargh! Esta carne **sabe** a ranço.
>
> Esta sopa **sabe mal** que se farta.
>
> Saudade é dor que não dói, Doce ventura cruel, É talho que fecha em falso, É veneno e sabe a mel.. ([Simões Lopes Neto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%A3o_Sim%C3%B5es_Lopes_Neto), *Contos Gauchescos*, 1912.)

Pode também ser usado acerca de coisas que não se saboreiam com a língua:

> Não tinha vergonha de dizer aos quatro ventos que vivia apaixonada. Naquele tempo, aqui nesta terrinha, isso valia como afronta aos costumes, era falta de recato, sabia a indecências. ([Francisco Dantas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Dantas_(Rio_Grande_do_Norte)), *Cartilha do Silêncio*, 1997.)
>
> Esta brisa fresca na cara **sabe-me** mesmo bem.
>
> A curiosidade instigava-o a andar para diante; por bom humor talvez, **sabia-lhe bem** aquela caminhada. ([Júlia Lopes de Almeida](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%BAlia_Lopes_de_Almeida), *A Falência*, 1901.)
>
> [...] Margarida, um pesadelo, deitava sem alegria, findava o serviço e pronto, ele mesmo já provara, **sabia a coisa nenhuma** [...] ([Caio Fernando Abreu](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caio_Fernando_Abreu), *Onde Andará Dulce Veiga*, 1990.)

Agora as achegas dos comentadores abaixo:

> As férias foram ótimas, mas **souberam a pouco**. (Queria mais.)
>
> O jantar foi bom. **Soube a pato**. (Ou a penas, alguém inesperadamente e sem grande razão para isso pagou-mo.)

E depois há ainda uma coisa que, não obstante o mau exemplo da Margarida do Caio Abreu, sabe mesmo mesmo bem, mas não é preciso entrar em pormenores, vocês já devem estar a ver o que é:

> Eu **saibo-te** a sal? Pudera, fizeste-me suar que nem um cavalo.

Comment: Acrescentaria só, em sentido figurado: "Foi bom, mas soube(-me) a pouco"

Comment: É tão normal, que existe a expressão "[saber a pato](https://sites.google.com/site/falarbragues/express%C3%B5es)".

Comment: @Artefacto Obrigado pela achega. Tinha-me esquecido dos significados figurados todos.

Comment: @ANeves Obrigado pela achega. Ainda continuo sem saber desses usos especiais da pontução que não transparecem na fala.

Comment: Dois comentários:  primeiro - aos nossos ouvidos de ultramar esse uso do verbo saber soa muito estranho.  segundo - porque o Silva de "da Silva" é escrito com letra maiúscula, uma vez que não se trata mais de um sobrenome e sim uma expressão idiomática?

Comment: Jacinto, gingar (/g/) é "bambolear", e ginja (/j/) é um fruto.

Comment: @Centaurus abre uma pergunta! :)

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, sim, a pergunta já explicita que o _saber_ de ter sabor soa estranho no Brasil. O objetivo da minha resposta, foi, bem responder à pergunta, que é sobre o seu uso em Portugal. _Silva_ com maiúscula, foi porque eu estava mesmo a pensar no sobrenome e não na planta. Mas se calhar deve ser mesmo escrito com minúscula.

Comment: @ANeves Obrigado pela correção. Vi o teu comentário, vi o texto; estava correto, e fiquei a pensar, que raio quer ele dizer. Só revendo as edições é que vi estava mal na versão inicial.

Comment: ((Ai, que confusão! Eu pensei que o teu comentário `continuo sem saber desses usos especiais da pontução que não transparecem na fala`, @Jacinto , era sobre o meu edit - por causa da palavra "pontuação"... e respondi como se fosse.))