# Porque se usa letra maiúscula em "da Silva", uma vez que a palavra não está senda usada como sobrenome e sim como expressão idiomática?

Tags: ortografia, maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

Exemplo:

- "Pensei que ele tivesse morrido."
- "Nâo, está vivinho da Silva."

Comment: Usa-se? Não fazia ideia.

Comment: Eu também não.  Mas vi escrito na pergunta sobre "saber" e perguntei porque.  Foi sugerido que eu postasse como pergunta.

Comment: Esta expressão idiomática significa o que exactamente? Se é uma brincadeira de palavras, construindo um nome inventado, seria então "Vivinho da Silva"?

Comment: @DanGetz "da Silva" significa "muito"  Nesse caso é para intensificar "vivo"

Comment: Então me parece que está senda usada como sobrenome sim: que quer dizer que a pessoa é tão vivo que seria a personificação de ser vivo, vida em pessoa. Eu podia escrever uma resposta, ma seria só suposição porque até hoje não conheci esta expressão.

Comment: Veja em inglês definição 2 de ["middle name" (to be someone's middle name)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/middle%20name). Não sei se o uso de estar é problema? É possivel *estar* uma certa pessoa, em vez de *ser*?

Comment: Uso da expressão que originou a pergunta: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1278/157

Comment: @DanGetz Boa Explicação!

Comment: @todos É de uso corrente no Brasil, embora já não tanto quanto no século passado.

Comment: @DanGetz Acho a tua ideia muito razoável. Por exemplo, "Mortinho da Silva" seria um alcunha plausível para alguém que andasse mortinho (=muito desejoso) por alguma coisa. No caso de _vivinho da silva_, também me parece que pode ser, mas aí também consigo associar à planta: a silva, indesejável nos terrenos agrícolas, é da plantas mais resistentes e difíceis de matar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É verdade que se usa letra maiúscula na expressão idiomática *da Silva*, mas apenas no sentido muito restrito e especioso de haver quem tenha escrito assim, nomeadamente eu [nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/uso-do-verbo-saber-no-sentido-de-ter-sabor-ou-gosto/1278#1278).

Agora, no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, a expressão aparece com minúscula:

> **da silva**, *locução adverbial popular*, inteiramente; completamente.

E possivelmente, em expressões como *vivinho da silva* ou *mortinho da silva*, eu teria escrito com minúscula também. Digo possivelmente porque não lembro de ter escrito ou lido a expressão antes.

A explicação para o meu uso da maiúscula é a seguinte. [A pergunta a que eu respondi](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/uso-do-verbo-saber-no-sentido-de-ter-sabor-ou-gosto) é se o uso do verbo *saber* de ter sabor (não *saber* de ter conhecimento) é habitual em Portugal. E eu respondi **normalíssimo da Silva** porque o que me veio à cabeça foi mesmo o sobrenome. Ou seja, *saber* de ter sabor é em Portugal tão normal como o sobrenome Silva. E vou manter: se necessário alego liberdade artística.

Agora não faço ideia se a expressão *da silva* tem origem no sobrenome ou na planta. O DACL inclui *da silva* dentro do verbete *silva* (que não inclui o sobrenome) e indica o latim *silva*, que significa floresta, como a origem de tudo. Mas o DACL não é o melhor dicionário para consultar etimologia. Mas de qualquer modo. não sei se a origem no sobrenome *Silva* justificaria a maiúscula.