# Donde vem o «silva» das expressões «mortinho da silva», «vivinho da silva», etc.?

Tags: etimologia, expressões

Usamos a locução [***da silva*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/silva) para enfatizar ou superlativar uma qualidade ou estado: alguém que está **mortinho da silva** está mesmo morto, ou muito cansado, ou desejoso; quem está **vivinho da silva** está bem vivo; quem é **doidinho da silva** é completamente doido; e não se pode ser mais normal que **normalíssimo da silva**.

À margem [desta pergunta sobre a grafia correta, se é *da silva* ou *da Silva*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/porque-se-usa-letra-mai%C3%BAscula-em-da-silva-uma-vez-que-a-palavra-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-send), já se especulou sobre possíveis origens da locução:

- Terá sido uma brincadeira: alguém estava tão vivo que foi alcunhado *Vivinho da Silva* por *Silva* ser um sobrenome muito comum? Ou alguém andava tão desejoso, mortinho, por alguma coisa ou alguém, que foi alcunhado *Mortinho da Silva*? E a locução generalizou-se a partir desses usos?
- Alguém ou algum animal ‘recusou-se’ a morrer, e foi alcunhado de *vivinho da silva*, por referência à planta? A silva é dificílima de matar: corta-se o caule abaixo do nível do solo, e ela vota a brotar das raízes.

Qualquer destas hipóteses é *a priori* plausível, mas carece de fontes ou exemplos de uso antigo para a fundamentar. E o que eu venho pedir aqui, é a resposta fundamentada: donde vem esta locução? Este «silva» tem que ver com a planta ou com o sobrenome? Quando e como é que apareceu a locução?

Comment: (Sem consultar base alguma) sempre tive a impressão de se referir ao sobrenome. O porquê de ser usada é algo que, espero, descoriremos!

Comment: Eu quando uso ou ouço, também associo ao sobrenome, sem conseguir explicar bem porquê. Agora se foi assim na origem da expressão é que já não sei. Estas coisas às vezes dão voltas e reviravoltas.

Comment: Sem quaisquer factos para substanciar a minha opinião subconscientemente sempre associei a expressão ao sobrenome.

Sempre presumi que era por ser um apelido muito comum (talvez a par com 'Santos' dos mais comuns) em Português, daí 'muito vivo' ou 'muito doido'. Ou talvez para dar ênfase no sentido de 'tão vivo' ou 'tão doido' que passou a fazer parte do seu nome.

Comment: Outra possível interpretação um pouco mais rebuscada: por vezes chama-se alguém pelo nome completo ou nome com apelidos para dar ênfase, ou intensificar a entoação (imagine uma mãe zangada). Outras vezes (desconhecendo o verdadeiro apelido) usa-se um nome genérico em lugar dos apelidos pela mesma razão ("Duarte Maria!" ou "Jacinto Maria!"). Será um caso semelhante em que se usa um nome genérico (Silva) apenas para ênfase verbal ou de entoação?

Comment: Acho que já discutimos pergunta semelhante aqui.

Comment: @Centaurus Não estarás a pensar na tua pergunta, se é silva com minúscula ou Silva com maiúscula, que eu referencio na pergunta?

Comment: No momento em que escrevi o comentário eu tinha uma vaga lembrança da pergunta, mas procurei e constatei que são diferentes embora sejam as duas sobre o "da Silva"

Answer (score 2):

Veio das sardinhas! Sim, sardinhas. Ao que parece tudo começou com o pregão com que as varinas anunciavam as sardinhas: ***vivinha da costa*** (do mar). A expressão entrou na linguagem popular; o pessoal naturalmente elaborou-a para ***vivinha da costa e silva***, e daí veio o *vivinho da silva*. Este foi o entendimento do filólogo brasileiro João Ribeiro [(*Frases Feitas*, [primeira edição de 1908], 2009, p. 177):](http://www.academia.org.br/sites/default/files/publicacoes/arquivos/frases_feitas_-_joao_ribeiro_-para_internet.pdf)

> Entretanto, a origem, ao que eu presumo, da locução está nas vozes de reclamo ou pregão das *vareiras* ou *varinas* (ovarinas) que vendem sardinhas com o grito habitual: “*Vivinha da costa! ainda viva!*”
>   Como *Costa* é nome de pessoa, originaram-se as variantes: vivinha da Costa e vivinha da Silva.

A propósito desta hipótese, diz outro filólogo brasileiro, Antenor Nascentes [(*A Gíria Brasileira*, 1953)](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22vivinha%20da%20Costa%20e%20vivinha%20da%20Silva.%20Costa%20e%20Silva%22&oq=%22vivinha%20da%20Costa%20e%20vivinha%20da%20Silva.%20Costa%20e%20Silva%22&gs_l=serp.3...4072.6442.0.6775.2.2.0.0.0.0.92.164.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.04hBCQsQV7Q), que «[f]rancamente não convence», mas adianta que «até agora ninguém aventurou outra explicação».

Mas Antenor Nascentes não tinha o Google Books, e nós encontramos aí todos os elementos da hipótese de João Ribeiro. O pregão *vivinha da costa* para as sardinhas está bem atestado; *vivinho da costa*, com eu descobri com grande surpresa, aparece na literatura em Portugal com o mesmo sentido que *vivinho da silva*; e até encontramos no século XIX as duas expressões misturadas em *vivinho da costa e silva* (meu negrito em todas as citações):

> A Associação dos Jornalistas acabou e não acabou, dissolveu-se e não se dissolveu, morreu de morte macaca e ficou **vivinha da costa e silva**.
>   [[Rafael Bordalo Pinheiro, *O António*, 1887.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5nYWxZf8kh4C&q=vivinha&dq=vivinha&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw2deGrbrPAhUFORQKHdvRDA44ZBDoAQgkMAE)
>
> PIMPÃO como fructo: apreciar bocadinhos escolhidos dos mais laureados vates de outras eras, e cotejar o alto merecimento desses tosadores posthumos com o modesto valor dos tosadores—felizmente **vivinhos da costa— e Silva**.
>   [[*O Pimpão*, 1892-93.]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22felizmente%20vivinhos%20da%20costa%20e%20Silva%22&oq=%22felizmente%20vivinhos%20da%20costa%20e%20Silva%22&gs_l=serp.3...9590.9848.0.10290.2.2.0.0.0.0.88.169.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.DjQIs1Jv8f8)

Estes são os exemplos mais antigos que eu encontrei destas expressões. *Mortinho da silva, normalíssimo da silva*, etc. só bastante mais tarde.

O pregão *vivinha da costa* das varinas foi até notado por observadores estrangeiros. Eis [A. Cunnick Inchbold, *Lisbon & Cintra*, 1907](https://books.google.pt/books?id=k4xNAAAAMAAJ&q=vivinha&dq=vivinha&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi59IidtLrPAhUBChoKHVjEA8s4MhDoAQi8AjAv) (minha tradução do inglês):

> Ela é uma mulher robusta, ágil, embora não frequentemente alta, que palmilha as ruas com um passo leve como o ar, lenço voando ao vento, canastra destramente equilibrada sobre o chapéu charmoso, enquanto grita com todo o vigor dos seus fortes pulmões: ***Vivinha da Costa! É d’agora viva!***. Os mares dos portugueses parecem ser inesgotáveis, e não há águas mais ricas que as do Tejo e das costas adjacentes.

Eu nunca tinha ouvido *vivinho da costa*, nem a propósito de sardinhas nem de outra coisa qualquer, mas o que é acerto é que aparece na literatura em Portugal até ao presente. Nalguns casos, os autores relacionam explicitamente com as sardinhas:

> É claro que as personagens do *Candide* parecem de borracha: Pangloss apodrece de sífilis, enforcam-no, amarram-no ao mastro de uma galé, e reencontramo-lo sempre **vivinho da costa**.
>   [[Italo Calvino (tradução de José Colaço Barreiros), *Porquê ler os Clássicos?*, 2015.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=jmqICgAAQBAJ&pg=PT92&dq=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMmZLVirrPAhXJcRQKHX90CCwQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%22&f=false)
>
> Mas eu gostaria de ver a vossa descontracção, se o morto que está na casa mortuária, ali, assomasse no alto do muro, falando, **vivinho da costa**, como a sardinha que se pesca na praia da Caparica!
>   [[Fernando Barão (Portugal 1924 – ), *Estórias de Almada Antiga*, 1990]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%2C%20como%20a%20sardinha%20que%20se%20pesca%20na%20praia%20da%20Caparica%22&oq=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%2C%20como%20a%20sardinha%20que%20se%20pesca%20na%20praia%20da%20Caparica%22&gs_l=serp.3...2588.4591.0.4787.2.2.0.0.0.0.82.154.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.hu7dmM7JoZM)

Não sei se *vivinho da costa* chegou ao Brasil. Encontrei um único exemplo de um autor brasileiro, mas dado o título, pode ter sido coisa que ele apanhou em Portugal:

> Se não existisse tinha de ser inventado. Aqui temos a bordo, «stealing the show» (como dizem os ingleses), moço, **vivinho da costa**, conversador assombroso, fulgurante.
>   [[Agrippino Grieco (Brasil, 1888 – 1973) *Agrippino Grieco em Portugal*, 1953.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=C0UTAQAAMAAJ&q=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%22&dq=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMmZLVirrPAhXJcRQKHX90CCwQ6AEImQEwEw)

Ao contrário do *da silva*, o *da costa* parece não ter gerado versões duradouras com *mortinho, normalíssimo*, etc. Mas terão havido algumas tentativas, como mostra esta passagem de 1916 no [Boletim da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, vol. 10:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=QkJoZ3sBgdYC&q=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%22&dq=%22vivinho%20da%20costa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMmZLVirrPAhXJcRQKHX90CCwQ6AEIpgEwFQ)

> De um bi-semanário humorístico, *Os Ridículos* (n.º de 29 de Janeiro de 1916), transcrevo este passo: «Aquelles republicanos da velha guarda eram até alguma cousa **reaccionariosinhos da costa**». Provêm este modo de dizer do pregão tão usado em Lisboa — ***vivinha da costa***, salpicadinha da costa?

As varinas chegaram (da região de [Ovar]) a Lisboa no século XIX e tornaram-se em imagem de marca da capital [(arquivo municipal de Lisboa)](http://arquivomunicipal.cm-lisboa.pt/pt/noticias/varinas-um-simbolo-de-lisboa/), não admirando portanto que expressões suas tivessem entrado na linguagem corrente. Outra versão do pregão era *vivinha a saltar*, que até deu título de revista em 1903 [(*Boletim das Bibliothecas e Archivos Nacionaes*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=0Xo2AQAAMAAJ&q=vivinha&dq=vivinha&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw2deGrbrPAhUFORQKHdvRDA44ZBDoAQhDMAY) e também deixou ecos na literatura:

> —E quanto a futurismos ardentes, **vivinhos da costa**, a saltar como sardinhas?
>   [[*Olisipo: Boletim do Grupo “Amigos de Lisboa”*, vol. 15, 1952.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EPgWAQAAMAAJ&q=%22vivinhos%20da%20costa%22&dq=%22vivinhos%20da%20costa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzpKaflrrPAhULWRQKHdLyDrgQ6AEIPDAF)

As outras versões do *da silva* parecem ter aparecido mais tarde. Eis as que encontrei, por ordem de antiguidade:

> Retorcia de todo o jeito. Depois, parece que se foi espichando, espichando e tremendo que nem borracha. A mulher avoou a cobra no mato. Estava **mortinha da silva**.
>   [[Sabino de Campos, *Catimbó*, 1946]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=do4BAAAAMAAJ&q=%22mortinha%20da%20silva%22&dq=%22mortinha%20da%20silva%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTsPLzg7rPAhVDzxQKHWQ3BNsQ6AEIxgIwLA)
>
> Cinco dias depara de internado, verificou êle que si continuasse em tal sanatório, acabaria realmente **"maluquinho da silva"**... 
>   [[*Revista de Teatro*, 1947.]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=sbd%3A1&tbm=bks&q=%22acabaria%20realmente%20maluquinho%20da%20silva%22&oq=%22acabaria%20realmente%20maluquinho%20da%20silva%22&gs_l=serp.3...203577.207979.0.208841.19.19.0.0.0.0.194.2205.2j15.17.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.14.1798...30i10k1.bs49zlNy__o)
>
> Mais dois mêses de trabalho árduo e a nova tradução estaria **prontinha da silva**.
>   [[*Leitura*, nº 1-12 1957.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=TBFHAQAAIAAJ&q=%22tontinha%20da%20silva%22&dq=%22tontinha%20da%20silva%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiyaPqxMPPAhUJXD4KHYE-BK4Q6AEIPzAF)
>
> Alguns mesmo, lembrando o caso de um tio dêle que morrera na corrente, **doidinho da silva**, achavam que o Domingos estava era «fora da abscissa».
>   [[Renato Mazze Lucas, *Anum Branco*, 1961]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=sbd%3A1&tbm=bks&q=%22doidinho%20da%20silva%20achavam%20que%20o%20Domingos%22&oq=%22doidinho%20da%20silva%20achavam%20que%20o%20Domingos%22&gs_l=serp.3...107791.108728.0.109879.2.2.0.0.0.0.123.209.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.PDoCTOXN47I)

Outras versões, como *normalíssimo da silva*, não aparecem sequer no Google Books, o que suger serem ainda mais recentes.