# Qual a origem da expressão idiomática "que tal?"

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, origem

Acho intrigante a expressão "que tal?".  É o exemplo típico de uma expressão idiomática, uma vez que as duas palavras sozinhas não têm nenhum significado. Juntas adquiriram um significado porque nós, os falantes da língua, assim quisemos. Seria a forma mais curta de uma frase que originalmente era mais longa? Porque será que ficou "que tal"? Suponho que seja de uso corrente em pt-PT, mas não tenho certeza. Em pt-BR é de uso corrente, e facilmente entendida por todos.

- Acabei de lustrar meu carro. Tirei todos os arranhões. Que tal?
- Amor, olha o meu vestido novo. Que tal?

Minha pergunta é: qual a origem e o primeiro registro que se tem? É de uso corrente em pt-PT? Há alguma expressão semelhante nas línguas mais próximas do Português? (Galego, Castelhano)

Comment: No Uruguai se fala muito ¿Qué tal?, mas não tenho certeza se é bem a mesma coisa.

Comment: @eightShirt  Acho que ouvi na Argentina, mais como uma saudação do tipo: "como vai?"   Seria assim no Uruguai?

Comment: @ANeves   Deixa o meu "quisemos" sem acento, por favor.

Comment: Já ouvi com o significado de "como vai", mas talvez também possa ter o significado semelhante ao que usamos em pt-BR. Não sei se é uma fonte confiável, mas parece que isso sana nossa dúvida: http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/172182/what-does-que-tal-mean-in-spanish

Comment: Isso é tudo comum em Portugal também. Sempre entendi como encurtamento: *Acabei de lustrar o carro. Que tal?* ou *Que tal (está/ficou/achas) o meu carro? Acabei de o lustrar.* / *Olha o meu vestido novo. Que tal?* ou *Que tal (achas) o meu vestido novo*? Por cá ouve-se os dois tipos de frase, com ou sem o verbo.

Comment: @Jacinto    Assim entendo.  Mas porque "tal"?  O que é "tal" ?

Comment: Que tal ficou? Assim como tal fulano é o tal. Que = como, tal = objeto, o resto é subentendido "ficou".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estas construções são perfeitamente padrão também em Portugal. O ***que tal?*** dos teus exemplos é um fragmento que o interlocutor completa com a informação anterior. A pergunta completa seria:

> Que tal o meu carro?
> Que tal o meu vestido novo?

Aqui há um verbo omisso. Há muitos que ficariam ali bem:

> Que tal ficou/está/achas/te parece o meu carro?

Atualmente é mais comum omitir o verbo, mas encontram-se as frases completas:

> Então que tal achas o meu vestido novo? [(Almanach Bertrand, 1906.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=DYo4AQAAMAAJ&q=%22que%20tal%20achas%20o%20meu%20vestido%20novo%22&dq=%22que%20tal%20achas%20o%20meu%20vestido%20novo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwisKrktvQAhWmwlQKHXYlAyYQ6AEINjAA)
> Que tal ficou o meu retrato? [(Sérgio Cabral, *No Tempo de Ari Barroso*, 1993.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=X5JaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Que%20tal%20ficou%22&dq=%22Que%20tal%20ficou%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_8NLIotvQAhWnwlQKHWPrCPQQ6AEIhwEwCw)
> Que tal é êle?
> [(António Augusto Fagundes, *Destino de tal: novela gauchesca*, 1962.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qEwtAAAAYAAJ&q=%22que%20tal%20%C3%A9%22&dq=%22que%20tal%20%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizoJuQrMbQAhVCcBoKHZQQAbkQ6AEIkAIw)
> E que tal está o novo CD e DVD, o acústico *Bandadois*?
> [Entrevista de Gilberto Gil ao Estadão, 2009, via *Jeito Baiano*.)](https://jeitobaiano.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/entrevista-de-gilberto-gil-ao-estadao/)

Este ***que tal*** significa ‘como’; nalguns casos poderá ser ‘o que’ (*que tal te parece?*). E existe também pelo menos em Castelhano, que aliás partilha muitos dos nossos usos de *tal*. Talvez a saudação que mais comumente ouço a amigos de língua castelhana, espanhóis ou latino-americanos, seja precisamente *qué tal?*, onde tal como entre nós há um verbo omisso. No Spanish SE, a reposta mais votada a [esta pergunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2283/c%C3%B3mo-se-dice-hows-it-going/2284#2284) apresenta como equivalentes:

> ¿Qué tal?
> ¿Qué tal estás?
> ¿Qué tal va todo?
> ¿Qué tal andas?

Agora donde é que isto vem? Segundo o Houaiss ***tal*** vem do latim *talis,e*, onde significava ‘igual, semelhante, tão grande, tanto’. No português isto veio a dar uma porção de usos [(ver Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/tal), e os sentidos originais transparecem em muitos deles. Por exemplo:

> *Tal pai, tal filho* vem de *qual pai, tal filho* = *qual pai, igual, semelhante filho*.
>
> Nunca tal coisa vi = nunca vi coisa igual, semelhante; essa coisa; coisa assim.
>
> X, Y e outros que tal = e outros semelhantes, do mesmo tipo; outros assim; outros como X e Y.

Não é difícil imaginar o nosso *que tal*, ‘como’, a surgir no meio disto tudo. Em muitos usos, *tal X* significa *X assim*; nós não perguntamos *que assim é isso?* porque não nos deu para aí: em vez disso perguntamos *como é isso?* ou *que tal é isso?*

Este uso já vem pelo menos do século XVI. O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei é da obra de [Gil Vicente (1465 – 1537; Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Vicente):

> Que tal te parece este pastor que aqui vem em nossa companhia?
> [(Gil Vicente, *Obras Completas*, 1966.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1AkKAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Que%20tal%20te%20parece%22&dq=%22Que%20tal%20te%20parece%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU08POpNvQAhUpxFQKHU9sBL8Q6AEIbjAL)

Depois temos um exemplo de [1552, no romance de cavalaria *Palmeirim de Inglaterra*, de Francisco Moraes](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ZjzuAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA192&dq=%22queria%20que%20me%20disseis%20que%20tal%20%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiemb2_psbQAhXDPBoKHYgAAggQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22queria%20que%20me%20disseis%20que%20tal%20%C3%A9%22&f=false):

> A empreza , que dizeis que jure , queria que me disseis , que tal é ;

Neste caso, parece-me que *que tal* significa ‘que isso’ [(Aulete 2)](http://www.aulete.com.br/tal). Mas também poderia ser ‘como’. Esta plasticidade do *tal* provavelmente facilitou a proliferação de usos que lhe viemos a dar.

No século XVIII encontrei o primeiro uso sem verbo, aqui facilitado por haver um verbo na frase anterior (ênfase minha):

> **Que tal foi** vossa devoção , e sorte? **Que tal o** milagre do vosso idolo ?
> [(Joaquim de Santa Rita, *Academia dos Humildes  e Ignorantes*, 1762.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=XVkDAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA322&dq=%22que%20tal%20foi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF-4HQuMbQAhVJChoKHdKABBMQ6AEIswIwJA#v=onepage&q=%22que%20tal%20foi%22&f=false)

Mas em [1824, n’*O Spectador Brasileiro*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LTRKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA140&dq=%22que%20tal%20o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVgo2J-cbQAhVTahoKHac1API4MhDoAQiFATAO#v=onepage&q=%22que%20tal%20o%22&f=false), já temos um exemplo cem por cento sem verbo:

> Meteo muita gente na folia , jurou , e tornou a jurar de não desamparar o campo da batalha […] e nesse mesmo dia (12 do passado) sem dizer aqui ficaõ as chaves, voou para bordo da corveta Ingleza, e lá foi por esses mares zombando de todos—**Que tal o maganão?**

E o resto é aquilo que nós sabemos.

Comment: Perfeito.  Podes reunir todas as tuas respostas aqui do site e mandar publicar em um livro "Curiosidades da Língua Portuguesa".  Eu comprarei um exemplar.

Comment: @Centaurus Quando me aposentar...

Comment: *¿Qué tal?* é, por ser tão idiomático, a saudação mais comum entre todos os países castelhano-falantes (porque não obriga a flexão do verbo, assim evita ter de escolher a formalidade).  Usa-se também no asturiano e galego.  Mas no português, que saiba eu, não se pode usar (ou pelo menos, teria de ser de uso muito menos frequente) sem verbo e sem nome como saudação, não é?

Comment: @guifa Nós, pelo menos em Portugal, não usamos a habitualmente *que tal?* como saudação; quando usamos é normalmente com verbo: *que tal tens passado? que tal corre a vida?* Podemos dizer  no follow-up da saudação *que tal as coisas lá em casa, no trabalho?, portanto sem verbo.

Comment: @Centaurus Portanto tu estás mais habituado a "X. Que tal?" em vez de *Que tal X?*

Comment: Já fui à Argentina várias vezes e fui muito saudado com "Que tal?"   Aqui no Brasil não ouço mas pode ser que no Rio Grande do Sul alguém use.  Teria que perguntar ao Gmauch.   @Jacinto estou habituado aos dois: "Maria, que tal irmos à praia amanhã?", "Que tal irmos à praia amanhã, Claudia?"

Comment: Não tenho registros documentados a respeito desta minha adição, a não ser o uso e costume em família de formação tradicional paulista. Sua inserção “X, Y e outros que *tal* = e outros semelhantes...”, me sabe estranha, uma vez que desde pequena ouço o que me possibilita traduzir sua frase como “X, Y e outros que ***tais***”, a corroborar assim o seu próprio uso do substituto “semelhantes”, notando-se o uso do plural no exemplo da inserção a que me refiro aqui.

Comment: Niuza, creio que aqui em Portugal se diz as duas coisas, "outros que tal" e "outros que tais", ambos significando 'outros semelhantes'. Ache curioso o teu "me sabe estranha". O uso de "saber" com o significado 'ter sabor' é comum em Portugal, mas pensava que não era no Brasil; vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/uso-do-verbo-saber-no-sentido-de-ter-sabor-ou-gosto). Agora outra coisa, Tu fizeste na verdade um comentário à minha resposta, no espaço reservado a respostas à pergunta lá em cima. Vamos ver se um moderador caridoso converte isto em comentário.

Comment: Olá, @Jacinto. Obrigada pela réplica. O uso do "saber" aí... acho que foi a ocorrência do registro da norma culta acontecendo automaticamente (saindo pelo ladrão, como se diz por aqui). Ainda não me inteirei dos usos e costumes deste site. Vou ler agora as regras. Obrigada, novamente, e Feliz Ano Novo.

Comment: @Jacinto   "me sabe estranha" não é exatamente comum no Brasil.  Está restrito a quem é bem versado na língua portuguesa.

Comment: @Jacinto  Há também "ele é o tal"  onde "o tal", com a adição do artigo, não parece ter nada a ver com o "que tal", sendo uma outra expressão idiomática.   Em tempo, no Brasil, "empresa" é escrito com "s".