# A expressão "e tal" tem alguma relação com o latim "et al."?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica

Ou será apenas coincidência que tanto a escrita como o significado sejam  aproximados?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apenas uma coincidência, uma vez que a palavra "tal" é usada em diversas expressões, **tais** como "que tal", "tal qual", ou "coisa e tal". A origem da palavra é latina, e bem explicada por Jacinto em [**uma resposta**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/qual-a-origem-da-express%C3%A3o-idiom%C3%A1tica-que-tal) a outra pergunta.

[**"et al"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/et%20al.) também vem do latim, significa "e outros", e é uma forma abreviada de "et alii" (masculino), et aliae (feminino) ou et alia (neutro).

É uma expressão muito utilizada na literatura científica, quando não se quer citar todos os autores de um trabalho, estudo ou pesquisa (fulano, et al.). Deve ser precedido de uma vírgula e seguido de um ponto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Há um pormenor que me está a confundir: a citação acima não está presente na resposta que foi referenciada -- terá sido apenas um erro de formatação?

Comment: @waldyrious   A resposta referenciada é sobre a origem de "tal" e pode ser encontrada em um trecho dela.

Comment: Não sei se me expliquei bem. O meu comentário é sobre o texto *"et al" também vem do latim, ...*, que está formatado como uma citação, mas que não encontro em http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3896 (nem faria sentido lá estar, já que essa pergunta é sobre "que tal" e não sobre "et al."). Daí ter perguntado se teria sido um erro de formatação :)

Comment: @waldyrious   Está lá sim, na resposta do Jacinto, no seguinte parágrafo: "Agora donde é que isto vem? Segundo o Houaiss tal vem do latim talis,e, onde significava ‘igual, semelhante, tão grande, tanto’. No português isto veio a dar uma porção de usos (ver Aulete), e os sentidos originais transparecem em muitos deles."