# "Saber bem" pode ser metafórico?

Tags: português-europeu, expressões-idiomáticas

Fiquei curiosa para saber se a expressão *saber bem* pode ser usada no sentido metafórico. Por exemplo, uma ideia pode saber bem? Algo como:

> Estou pensando em reservar um hotel que tem uma vista linda para as montanhas. Sabe bem, não é?

Comment: Não creio que possa, não me soa bem.

Comment: Tal como ao @ANeves, esse teu exemplo soa-me estranho, mas *saber* (no sentido 'ter sabor') pode ser usado figuradamente. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/uso-do-verbo-saber-no-sentido-de-ter-sabor-ou-gosto?rq=1), que tem alguns exemplos desse uso.

Comment: Ali na outra pergunta que o @Jacinto ligou, acho que estes exemplos em concreto são usos metafóricos de "ter sabor ou gosto": `(...) sabia-lhe bem aquela caminhada` e `Esta brisa fresca na cara sabe-me mesmo bem.` Talvez isto possa ser usado como base para uma resposta.

Comment: Mais um voto pelo "não". E eu diria que em português brasileiro deve soar ainda mais estranho que no europeu.

Comment: Mais um voto pelo "não", concordando com @stafusa.  Nunca ouvi algo semelhante no Brasil. A mim soa muito estranho.  Já, "sabia-lhe bem aquela caminhada..." conforme citado por ANeves, não soa tão estranho, embora pareça ter saído de um livro de Machado de Assis.

Comment: Je sais bien (savoir bien) que tu penses que saber bem veut dire la même chose en portuguais.

Answer (score 1):

[Saber (Aulete 9)](http://www.aulete.com.br/saber) pode significar ’ter sabor’: *este vinho sabe mal, o bolo sabe a limão*. Este uso é comum em Portugal e também aparece na literatura brasileira (ver [esta pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/uso-do-verbo-saber-no-sentido-de-ter-sabor-ou-gosto?noredirect=1&lq=1). Pode perfeitamente ser metafórico:

> Este solzinho sabe tão bem!
>
> Soube-me muito bem este bocadinho aqui contigo

O teu exemplo não me soou lá muito bem, mas, pensando bem, uma ideia pode saber bem. Não consigo bem atinar com o que é que não gosto no teu exemplo, mas a reformulação seguinte já me soa bem; imagina que estás a falar com uma pessoa que iria contigo para o hotel:

> Estou pensando reservar um hotel que tem um vista linda para as montanhas. Sabe-te bem a ideia?

Isto, em Portugal, seria interpretado como, “agrada-te a ideia de irmos passar uns dias num hotel tal e tal?”

Encontrei alguns exemplos reais deste tipo (negrito meu):

> Um regresso ao caos. Lento, mas não tanto que nos poupe à antevisão das catástrofes. Até **sabe bem a ideia** de morrer antes.
>   [Urbano Tavares Rodrigues, *Ao contrário das ondas*, 2005, p. 117](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ec9-emqmid4C&pg=PA117&dq=%22sabe%20bem%20a%20ideia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3hsb-yoLcAhVL7IMKHWNnD80Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22sabe%20bem%20a%20ideia%22&f=false~)
>
> Na primeira segunda-feira deste novo ano **sabe-me bem a ideia** de acabar o dia a ouvir Vasco Pinto de Magalhães falar sobre a fé cristã e o sentido de pertença. A entrada é livre e o encontro vai ser às 21:15 no Grande Auditório das Irmãs Vicentinas
>   [Laurinda Alves, *A substância da vida* (blog), 2011](https://laurindaalves.blogs.sapo.pt/430714.html)

Também pode saber bem saber que alguma coisa é verdade ou pensar nalguma coisa:

> […] **sabe bem pensar** que amanhã, depois do almoço, vai haver castanhas assadas
>   [*Mais do Mesmo*, (blog), 2008](https://mais-do-mesmo.blogs.sapo.pt/6212.html)
>
> Numa altura em que o sol e o calor não têm abundado, **sabe bem pensar** no verão e naquelas férias relaxantes que já pode começar a planear.
>   [*Notícias ao Minuto*, 2017](https://www.noticiasaominuto.com/economia/792237/esqueca-a-chuva-e-descubra-as-praias-mais-baratas-para-as-suas-ferias)
>
> **Sabe bem saber** que apesar do calor do dia, a noite de Cali sempre traz uma brisa que levanta saias e refresca, sem fazer frio.
>   [Filipa Chatillon, *Contos Alfacinhas* (blog), 2016](http://www.contosalfacinhas.com/rotinas/)
>
> Há tantas coisas que os brasileiros têm que nós queremos. **Sabe bem saber** que mesmo assim, Deus os abençoe, nunca hão de estar satisfeitos.
>   [Miguel Esteves Cardoso, “Cartas Brasileiras”, *Publico*, 5-3-2014](https://www.publico.pt/2014/03/05/culturaipsilon/opiniao/cartas-brasileiras-1627018)

Answer (score 1):

*Saber* pode ser usado, por extensão, para um sentimento em vez da sensação do paladar. Um exemplo a juntar aos do Jacinto:

> «**Sabe-me muito mal** o que se está a passar no São Carlos» e a crise «não é nada boa para a imagem do Teatro no meio artístico internacional». CETEMPúblico (ref. ext1483348-clt-95b)

Este uso é análogo a «cai-me muito mal»; aí a metáfora é mais à frente no tubo digestivo. É parafraseável por algo como «causa-me um sentimento desagradável».

Concordo com os restantes participantes quando dizem que a tua frase não é aceitável:

> Estou pensando em reservar um hotel que tem uma vista linda para as montanhas. **Sabe bem, não é**?

Creio que o principal problema da frase é o sujeito (omitido) de *saber*. Que coisa *sabe*? O sujeito que mais facilmente se subentenderia seria *pensar em reservar o hotel*. Mas o que pode *saber bem* («ser bom») é **experimentar** a "vista linda para as montanhas" ou, mais geralmente, a estadia no tal hotel. Se corrigirmos este problema adicionando um sujeito explícito, a frase já fica aceitável:

> Estou pensando reservar um hotel que tem um vista linda para as montanhas. **Sabe bem** mudar de vistas, não é?

Aqui, «sabe bem» pode ser parafraseado por «é bom».

A correção que o Jacinto propõe acrescenta também um sujeito explícito, está talvez mais perto da tua ideia original, e é certamente mais aceitável do que a original:

> Estou pensando reservar um hotel que tem um vista linda para as montanhas. **Sabe-te bem a ideia**?

Repara que neste uso, «saber» já não diz respeito a um experimentador genérico (tal com em «é bom»), mas ao intercolutor, a quem é pedida uma opinião. Eu preferiria, contudo, «parece-te» ou, quando muito, «cheira-te». Pode certamente «saber-se» uma ideia, mas aqui o argumento subentendido mais acessível para *ideia* é «reservar um hotel que tem uma vista linda para as montanhas». *Fazer uma reserva* não é em si uma experiência muito rica. Em minha opinião, seria mais aceitável:

> Adoro passar o verão nas montanhas. **A ti sabe-te bem** a ideia [de passar o verão nas montanhas]?

Comment: Concordo que, na minha sugestão, o argumento à vista para "ideia" é "reservar o hotel", mas creio que toda a gente interpretaria a pergunta como "sabe-te bem a ideia [de passar uns dias/tempos no hotel]", precisamente porque reservar o hotel só por si não é coisa que saiba bem; o objetivo da reserva, passar lá uns dias, é que pode saber bem. Estes saltos de lógica (como da reserva para o seu objetivo) são muito comuns na linguagem.

Comment: @Jacinto Pela forma como o teu exemplo está formulado, a pergunta parece-me mais pedir a opinião do interlocutor ou mesmo a sua anuência e ser parecido a "Parece-te bem a ideia de reservar o hotel?" ou, mais generosamente, "Parece-te bem a ideia de passar uns tempos nesse hotel?" e _saber_ parece-me caber mal na frase. Mas o mesmo se aplica frase que sugiro no fim, na medida em que pode ser interpretada como um convite.